# add select form validator

Tags: javascript, html

i use this code for validate input text and input checkbox . but i want add select box validate to required function . i want user have to select one string and select box fill .

```
required:{
            set:function(val) {
                //Check the type of the input
                switch(this.tagName) {
                    case 'INPUT':
                        if($(this).attr('type') == 'text') {
                            val = $.trim(val);
                            if(val === '') {
                                return false;
                            }else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }else if($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
                            return $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
                        }
                        break;  
                    default:
                        return false;
                        break;
                }
            },
            message:'This field is required.'
        },
```

but i dont know what and where add code .

Comment: If you write the code then you know where add code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
    return $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
}
else if($(this).attr('select') == '') {
    if(val === '') {
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: after else if write another else if